# How to determine if A->B line resides in the polygon without hitting any walls?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

Okay, buckle up.

Given a Linestring which is constructed from Point A and B and a polygon C how can I assure that A->B line does not intersect with any walls in C or resides inside the C?

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

typedef bgm::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef bgm::polygon<Point> Polygon;
typedef boost::geometry::model::segment<Point> Segment;
Polygon wall;
Polygon passage;
boost::geometry::model::linestring<Point> AB{start, end}
bool isPassable = false;
bool intersecting = bg::intersects(AB, wall);
if (intersecting) {
    for (int i = 0; i < passage.outer().size(); i += 2) {
      Point p1 = passage.outer()[i];
      Point p2 = passage.outer()[i + 1];
      Segment passageSegment(p1, p2);
      Segment testSegment(start, end);
      if (bg::intersects(passageSegment, testSegment)) {
        isPassable = true;
        break;
      }
    }
} else {
    isPassable = bg::relate(AB, wall, boost::geometry::de9im::mask("T*F**F***"));
}
```

Due to privacy reasons, I cant show the full code but this is the point of interest anyways.

Our polygon in question

```cpp
POLYGON((2 2,2 3.5,4 3.5,4 2,2 3.5,2 5.5,5 5.5,5 3.5,4 2,4 3.5,5 3.5,5 5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2))
```

passages

```cpp
Passage: POINT(2.5 3.5) POINT(3 3.5)
Passage: POINT(4.25 3.5) POINT(4.75 3.5)
Passage: POINT(4 2.5) POINT(4 3)
Passage: POINT(5 4) POINT(5 5)
```

looks like this:

[image]

Where the green line is:

```cpp
POINT(2.5 3.25) POINT(3 3.625)
```

After running the two relate functions `see if this line is related to any walls, if it is not related, check if it is breaching any holes in passages`, this works, actually. For the green line, I can get a `true`. Problem starts at:

[image]

this green line. As you can see it lies in the polygon. So in the first `relate` to the wall it should return true. but as there is no relation between the line and walls/passages, this one returns `false` even through it shouldn't. How can I handle this?

In official Boost doc

https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/relate.html

I can see that

[image]

This method is actually used for the thing I want. See if the point of interest resides in the polygon.
thanks for any help.

Comment: See if the segment intersects any segments of the polygon.  If it does not, check either endpoint to see if it's within the polygon.

Comment: So if https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html is False, use within again to check if it is in the polygon? If both is False, then line is not in the polygon or is not related with walls?

Comment: Tried `if intersecting with the walls, check if you are intersecting with any passages, if yes, return True. if not intersecting with the walls, check if line is in the polygon, if yes return True. false for every other case` and it did not work for the second case again. https://paste.com.tr/iiryyxuj

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869456/4641116

Comment: I currently have that exact same setup Eljay. I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: Is `passage.outer().size()` always an even number?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, walls and passages are always an even number so we cant go out of bounds even if we wanted to.

Comment: Added missing 4th passage, sorry for that.

Comment: You were also missing the second green line specs (manually guesstimated at `{6, 3.5}, {6.25, 4}`, which is harder than it needed to be since neither origin or scale were present)

Comment: @sehe dude :( so sorry for that. apologizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input polygon is invalid:

```
Polygon wall;
bg::read_wkt( //
    "POLYGON((2 2,2 3.5,4 3.5,4 2,2 3.5,2 5.5,5 5.5,5 3.5,4 2,4 3.5,5 3.5,5 "
    "5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2)) ",
    wall);

if (std::string reason; !bg::is_valid(wall, reason)) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid polygon: " << reason << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17f214bc22f21bac)**

> `Invalid polygon: Geometry has invalid self-intersections. A self-intersection point was found at (2, 3.5); method: t; operations: i/u; segment IDs {source, multi, ring, segment}: {0, -1, -1, 0}/{0, -1, -1, 3}`

You can attempt to fix it automatically with `bg::correct`

```
for (std::string reason; !bg::is_valid(wall, reason); bg::correct(wall)) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid polygon: " << reason << "\n";
}
```

But it doesn't work for these problems. I strongly suspect you really want the  thing to be a (multi-)linestring, or even just a list of segments.

Then to get the "within" check you'd use [`bg::within`](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) against the convex hull¹.

With those fixes I get:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f56d1a13cdddf64)**

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>
namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

using Point    = bgm::d2::point_xy<double>;
using Polygon  = bgm::polygon<Point>;
using Segment  = boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>;
using Segments = std::vector<Segment>;
using String   = bgm::linestring<Point>;
using MString  = bgm::multi_linestring<String>;

int main() {
    String wall
        // {{2, 2}, {2, 3.5}, {4, 3.5}, {4, 2},   {2, 3.5},   {2, 5.5}, {5, 5.5},
        // {5, 3.5}, {4, 2}, {4, 3.5}, {5, 3.5}, {5, 5.5}, {7.5, 5.5}, {7.5, 2}, {2, 2}}
        //
        ;

    bg::read_wkt(
        "LINESTRING(2 2,2 3.5,4 3.5,4 2,2 3.5,2 5.5,5 5.5,5 3.5,4 2,4 3.5,5 3.5,5 "
        "5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2)",
        wall);

    for (std::string reason; !bg::is_valid(wall, reason); bg::correct(wall)) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid wall: " << reason << "\n";
    }

    Polygon hull;
    bg::convex_hull(wall, hull);

    std::cout << "Wall is " << bg::wkt(wall) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hull is " << bg::wkt(hull) << std::endl;

    //Segment AB({2.5, 3.25}, {3, 3.625});
    Segment AB({6, 3.5}, {6.25, 4});

    Segments passages{
        {{2.5, 3.5}, {3, 3.5}},
        {{4.25, 3.5}, {4.75, 3.5}},
        {{4, 2.5}, {4, 3}},
        {{5, 4}, {5, 5}},
    };

    bool isPassable = false;
    if (/*bool intersecting =*/bg::intersects(AB, wall)) {
        for (auto& passage : passages) {
            if (bg::intersects(passage, AB)) {
                isPassable = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        bgm::linestring<Point> abls({AB.first, AB.second});
        isPassable = bg::within(abls, hull);
    }

    std::cout << "Is passable: " << std::boolalpha << isPassable << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
Wall is LINESTRING(2 2,2 3.5,4 3.5,4 2,2 3.5,2 5.5,5 5.5,5 3.5,4 2,4 3.5,5 3.5,5 5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2)
Hull is POLYGON((2 2,2 5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2))
Is passable: true
```

I would really suggest to simplify it further by actually *deleting* the passages from the original "wall" string. This is especially important to make your check correct. After all, when there are multiple intersections one of them being in a passage really doesn't change anything, but your code assumes there is always only one intersection.

### BONUS

This take (still assuming the convex hull) should be correct for multiple intersections. Note also that it is became considerably simpler. And we assert that the passages actually lie on the walls.

I've added more test-cases to showcase different edge cases.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3611942d5714a5d6)**

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>
namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = boost::geometry::model;

using Point    = bgm::d2::point_xy<double>;
using MPoint   = bgm::multi_point<Point>;
using Polygon  = bgm::polygon<Point>;
using Segment  = boost::geometry::model::segment<Point>;
using Segments = std::vector<Segment>;
using String   = bgm::linestring<Point>;
using MString  = bgm::multi_linestring<String>;

int main() {
    String const wall{{2, 2},   {2, 3.5}, {4, 3.5},   {4, 2},   {2, 3.5},
                      {2, 5.5}, {5, 5.5}, {5, 3.5},   {4, 2},   {4, 3.5},
                      {5, 3.5}, {5, 5.5}, {7.5, 5.5}, {7.5, 2}, {2, 2}};

    Polygon hull;
    bg::convex_hull(wall, hull);

    std::cout << "Wall is " << bg::wkt(wall) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hull is " << bg::wkt(hull) << std::endl;

    MString const passages{
        {{2.5, 3.5}, {3, 3.5}},
        {{4.25, 3.5}, {4.75, 3.5}},
        {{4, 2.5}, {4, 3}},
        {{5, 4}, {5, 5}},
    };

    assert(passages.size() == 4);
    assert(bg::within(passages, wall));

    for (auto AB : {
             String{{2.5, 3.25}, {3, 3.625}},
             String{{6, 3.5}, {6.25, 4}},
             String{{3.5, 3.25}, {4, 3.625}},
             String{{3.5, 1.25}, {4, 1.625}},
             String{{3.5, 1.75}, {4, 2.125}},
         }) {
        std::cout << "\n---- Test AB " << bg::dsv(AB) << " ----\n";

        MPoint w_isect, p_isect;
        bg::intersection(wall, AB, w_isect);
        bg::intersection(passages, AB, p_isect);
        std::cout << "Intersecting wall:" << bg::dsv(w_isect)
                  << " Passage:" << bg::dsv(p_isect) << std::endl;

        bool const isPassable =                       //
            (w_isect.empty() && bg::within(AB, hull)) //
            || (w_isect.size() == p_isect.size());

        std::cout << "Is passable: " << isPassable << " ("
                  << (bg::disjoint(AB, hull) ? "disjoint" : "")
                  << (bg::within(AB, hull) ? "within" : "") //
                  << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Wall is LINESTRING(2 2,2 3.5,4 3.5,4 2,2 3.5,2 5.5,5 5.5,5 3.5,4 2,4 3.5,5 3.5,5 5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2)
Hull is POLYGON((2 2,2 5.5,7.5 5.5,7.5 2,2 2))

---- Test AB ((2.5, 3.25), (3, 3.625)) ----
Intersecting wall:((2.83333, 3.5)) Passage:((2.83333, 3.5))
Is passable: 1 (within)

---- Test AB ((6, 3.5), (6.25, 4)) ----
Intersecting wall:() Passage:()
Is passable: 1 (within)

---- Test AB ((3.5, 3.25), (4, 3.625)) ----
Intersecting wall:((3.83333, 3.5)) Passage:()
Is passable: 0 (within)

---- Test AB ((3.5, 1.25), (4, 1.625)) ----
Intersecting wall:() Passage:()
Is passable: 1 (disjoint)

---- Test AB ((3.5, 1.75), (4, 2.125)) ----
Intersecting wall:((4, 2.125), (3.91667, 2.0625), (4, 2.125), (3.83333, 2)) Passage:()
Is passable: 0 ()
```

---

¹ (If your shapes are more complex than depicted and can have concave edges, then you need to adapt for that still).

Comment: Added a BONUS take that alleviates some of the correctness concerns while simplifying the implementation, and adding more test cases at the same time!

Comment: wish I could kiss you right now, this works like a charm. thank you so much for extensive answer mate.

Comment: also why `using` instead of `typedef` I saw that in other people's code too, what is the difference?

Comment: It's just more the more versatile c++ language feature instead of the C language feature that is harder to read too :) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias